# Pure CSS sibling selectors

Tags: css, siblings

```html
<style>
#b2-Column1 {
    background-color:red;
    min-height:120px;
}

#b2-Column1 > div {
    background-color:yellow;
    min-height:100px;
}

</style>

<div id="b2-Column1">
<div><!-- some comments here's --></div>
</div>
```

How can I do, if the yellow section is empty, then I want to both red and yellow setting to display:none;

Comment: you can't move backward in CSS

Comment: If you set the min-height and :not(:emtpty) selector on the child,  you may keep the parent to be 0 of height. You have to think otherwise  ;) if updating the structure and js are no options. Answer stands already below. See what you can do from it.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to hide the yellow part with [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class, however, as [we don't have a parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), you will have to look for JavaScript solution for the red part.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 120px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.child:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"><!-- some comments here's --></div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not change the structure, it generates from some builder. So the main point is how can display:none , when the yellow section is nothing content, both yellow and red section set disable.

Comment: the DOM structure is the same as your example. the gist of the snippet is the `:empty` selector which could be easily reused in your case. still, as said in the answer, there is not too much you can do with the red part.

Comment: However, if your requirement is to make these `div`s `disabled`, there is a trick, make the yellow box `disabled`, enlarge it and make it cover the entire red box

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do from Jquery then apply this:-

```
if($("#b2-Column1 > div").text() != ''){
    console.log('Not Emtpy');
}
else{
    console.log('Empty');
    $("#b2-Column1 > div,#b2-Column1").hide();
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what "Pure CSS" means?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do this in CSS, my application is not accepted use JS or Jquery